# Convert [a b c] to [a,b,c] with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, tuples

i want to convert the list like `[a b c]` to `[a,b,c]` in python 3

my list:

`[john jr 0, Akbar AK 1001, doctor rd 9999, Mohammedans med 1000, pat mat 200, cajole Jul 21]`

i want to sum the int of this list! how can i do it ?

Comment: Where are you getting your input from?  Is it a string like `"[john jr 0, doctor rd 9999]"` or a list of strings like `["john jr 0", "doctor rd 9999"]`, or is it in some other format?

Comment: your input is not syntactically valid so we can only guess what you mean

Comment: First, you list is not correct, since it seems to be missing string characters as Patrick Haugh points out. Secondly, it's not clear what you mean with "i want to sum the int of this list! how can i do it ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this does not work...

```
a = [john jr 0, Akbar AK 1001, doctor rd 9999, Mohammedans med 1000, pat mat 200, cajole Jul 21]
```

because it is not python valid syntax.
So I assume you mean

```
a = "[john jr 0, Akbar AK 1001, doctor rd 9999, Mohammedans med 1000, pat mat 200, cajole Jul 21]"
```

We can split it into parts on a separator...
The default seperator is space " "
now our code is

```
s = "[john jr 0, Akbar AK 1001, doctor rd 9999, Mohammedans med 1000, pat mat 200, cajole Jul 21]"
s = s.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
s = s.replace(",", " ")
a = s.split()
print(s)
print(a)
```

and we get printed

```
[john jr 0, Akbar AK 1001, doctor rd 9999, Mohammedans med 1000, pat mat 200, cajole Jul 21]
['[john', 'jr', '0,', 'Akbar', 'AK', '1001,', 'doctor', 'rd', '9999,', 'Mohammedans', 'med', '1000,', 'pat', 'mat', '200,', 'cajole', 'Jul', '21]']
```

A bit hard to read and you probably don't want the leading and trailing brackets so we strip those.  the commas are going to cause number parsing errors so we replace those with spaces. Since spaces are the separator and we want any parts like 12,hi with no space to become 12 hi

Next lets find all the numbers and add those up. We have to simply try to parse each string as a number see if it succeeds.

```
s = "[john jr 0, Akbar AK 1001, doctor rd 9999, Mohammedans med 1000, pat mat 200, cajole Jul 21]"
s = s.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
s = s.replace(",", " ")
a = s.split()
print(s)
print(a)
mysum = 0.0
for w in a:
    print("Word is %s" % (w,))
    try:
        n = float(w)
        print("Found number %f" % (n,))
        mysum += n
    except:
        # Ignore any exceptions
        pass
print("Sum is %f" %(mysum,))
pass
```

And we get

```
john jr 0  Akbar AK 1001  doctor rd 9999  Mohammedans med 1000  pat mat 200  cajole Jul 21
['john', 'jr', '0', 'Akbar', 'AK', '1001', 'doctor', 'rd', '9999', 'Mohammedans', 'med', '1000', 'pat', 'mat', '200', 'cajole', 'Jul', '21']
Word is john
Word is jr
Word is 0
Found number 0.000000
Word is Akbar
Word is AK
Word is 1001
Found number 1001.000000
Word is doctor
Word is rd
Word is 9999
Found number 9999.000000
Word is Mohammedans
Word is med
Word is 1000
Found number 1000.000000
Word is pat
Word is mat
Word is 200
Found number 200.000000
Word is cajole
Word is Jul
Word is 21
Found number 21.000000
Sum is 12221.000000
```

So now we have working code that meets what you stated, it finds the numbers and adds them.
But is this maintainable and efficient and functional etc.
When I have the above problem I use some methods I made that make it easier.
Here they are.

```
def tryParseInt(value=None, default_value=0):
    """
    Try to parse a string value to an int.  Returns the value and True
    e.g.  tryParseInt("42", 7) returns (42, True)
    tryParseInt("abcdef", 7) returns (7, False)
    See twit_test.py
    """
    try:
        return int(value), True
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return default_value, False


def tryParseFloat(value=None, default_value=0.0):
    """
    Try to parse a string value to an float.  Returns the value and True
    e.g.  tryParseInt("42.42", 7.3) returns (42.42, True)
    tryParseInt("abcdef", 7.3) returns (7.3, False)
    See twit_test.py
    """
    try:
        return float(value), True
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return default_value, False


def split_strip(s: str, sep=' '):
    """ 
    Split s into parts on delimiter, then strip the sub strings and remove any blanks.
    Never returns None.
    Returns an array of the sub strings.  The returned array my be empty.
    See twit_test.py for examples.
    """
    if s is None:
        return []
    parts = s.split(sep=sep)
    ret = []
    if parts is not None:
        for ss in parts:
            sss = ss.strip()
            if len(sss) > 0:
                ret.append(sss)
    return ret
```

The above helpers are available on GitHib project https://github.com/RMKeene/twit

Answer (score 0):

I don't know english very well, but I think this is waht you expected

```
L = 'john jr 0, Akbar AK 1001, doctor rd 9999, Mohammedans med 1000, pat mat 200, 

cajole Jul 21'
L = L.split(',')
Sum_L = 0
for i in range(0,len(L)):
  L[i] = (L[i].strip()).split(' ')
  Sum_L = Sum_L + int(L[i][2])
print(Sum_L)
```